# Is every field has characteristic p>0 finitely generated?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $I \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a maximal ideal. Show that if $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ has characteristic $p > 0$, then $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is a finite field.

and I thought the forrowing proposition is useful for this:

> If a finitely generated ring K is a field, it is a finite field. (Atiyah-Macdonald, exercise7-7)

I know if a field K has characteristic $p>0$, then K includes a primary field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. But can I say then K is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-algebra then? In this case, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is a noetherian ring, so I thought it is finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-algebra but I think it's different a little bit, noetherian rings and finitely generated algebra.. I'm confused.

Comment: $k(x)$ is not finitely generated, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608735/prove-that-the-field-kx-of-rational-functions-over-k-in-the-variable-x-i?rq=1).

Comment: You have that $p\in I$. Now, look at the image of $I$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$. This should be generated by an irreducible monic polynomial $q(x)$. Then $I=(p, q(x))$. So, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is generated by the polynomials $ax^k$, for $a\in\{1,2,...,p-1\}$ and $k\in \{0,2,...,\deg(q)-1\}$.

Comment: @NDB Wow, I didn't know the maximal ideal $I$ is written as you wrote, it's so limited. And it's just a typo, $k$ is $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ... , \text{deg}(q) - 1\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, $k=1$ is also needed.

Comment: @NDB Thank you so much.